# parameterized target in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my Build.xml I have 2 target. How can I let my system show these 2 target option while running the build? So that I can choose specific target and run it.

```
<project name="buildtest>
<import file="build.macro.xml"/>
<target name="build">
    <smcfs-build />
</target>
<target name="buildsh">
    <smcfs-buildsh />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure a "Choice" parameter, populate the options with these two, one per line.

Comment: So how I can give target as variable? I am not able to find it.

Comment: Same way you would give from command line. How are you calling the actual ant build?